# How to get all folders & files based on Owner using PHP with Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How to get all files and folder based on owner?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQXyI.jpg

I tried this query but it is just listing all sharedWithMe :

```
<?php
        
        //fields can be use files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, trashed, permissions, webViewLink, webContentLink, exportLinks), nextPageToken
        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setAuthConfig('gdrive/json/'. $_SESSION['json'] . '.json');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
        $client->setSubject($_SESSION['json_email']);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
                
        
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($GLOBALS['client']);
            
            $parameters['pageSize'] = 250;
            $parameters['q'] = "sharedWithMe and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"; 
            //"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed=false";
            $parameters['fields'] = 'files(id, name,modifiedTime,owners), nextPageToken';
            //'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, trashed, permissions, webViewLink, webContentLink, exportLinks), nextPageToken'; 
                
            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
        
            foreach( $files as $k => $file ){
            echo " <tr>
                            <td><large><i class='ti-folder'></i></large>
                                ";
                $forlinkowners = $file['owners'];
                        foreach ($forlinkowners as $pp => $getowner2){
                            echo "<a href='rmsystems.php?shared&&id=".$file['id']."&&foldername=".$file['name']."&&email=".$getowner2['emailAddress']."'>";
                    
                            echo folder_from_rename($file['name']) . "&nbsp&nbsp<span class='badge badge-primary'>link</span>";
                                
                            echo "</a></td>
                             <td><i class='ti-crown'></i>&nbsp&nbsp".retrieve_name($getowner2['emailAddress']).
                                     "</td>"; 
                            }
                                echo "</tr> ";
                            }
            ?>
```

I just want to group them by their Owner. Any suggestions? How will I do it in PHP or Should I query it in google API?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is using sharedWithMe You should be using "owners  in"

```
"'test@example.org' in owners"
```

## from comment

You cant search on files not in a folder (parent) you can only search on files in a folder

`'root' in parents` will return all the files in root. However `'root' not in parents` will fail as its not valid.

Im 100% sure what you mean by parent key.  If you only want files in some directories i would suggest that you run requests for each of the directories you want and ignore the ones you dont.  This will mean multiple requests or just get everything and sort it locally.

#### Reference:

- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)

Comment: Hello sir! Thank you for replying, your code works! But how do I hide folders that has a parent key?

Comment: Hello madam,  Check my update really cant.

Comment: Hello sir daimto! Sorry I can't @ your name :D I'm actually a dude lol. Anyway sir I understand that it cannot be done In one query. I'm just having a hard time grouping it in PHP based on same parent id's.

Comment: I'll accept your answer sir since my question is how to retrieve all files and folders based on owner. But I do have one final question. How can I distinctively display all email address that has shared with me

Comment: I would search on all the files shared with me and use fields to display the email address of the owner.   If you cant get it to work open a new question i should spot it.